# List of abbreviations (acronym) on one page

Tags: tables, columns, acronyms

I created a list of abbreviations with the `\usepackage{acronym}`. Now I have a list, which is two pages long. I'd like to have the abbreviations in a table or in two columns on one page. How can I do this?

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[printonlyused,nohyperlinks]{acronym}




\begin{document}
\chapter{Abkürzungen}

\begin{acronym}
\acro{cf}[CF]{Carbon Microfaser}
\acro{eh}[EH]{Energy Harvesting}
\acro{ehs}[EHS]{Energy-Harvesting-System}
\acro{ekg}[EKG]{Elektrokardiogramm}
\acro{fem}[FEM]{Finite-Elemente-Methode}
\acro{hh}[HH]{Halb-Heusler-Verbindung}
\acro{ht}[HT]{Hochtemperatur}
\acro{imd}[IMD]{implantiertes medizinisches Gerät}
\acro{iot}[IoT]{Internet of Things}
\acro{nt}[NT]{Niedertemperatur}
\acro{pcu}[PCU]{Power Control Unit}
\acro{pf}[PF]{Power Factor}
\acro{pvc}[PVC]{Polyvinylchlorid}
\acro{rfid}[RFID]{Radiofrequenz Identification}
\acro{sc}[SC]{Supply Chain}
\acro{sps}[SPS]{Funkenplasma-Sintern}
\acro{te}[TE]{thermoelektrisch}
\acroplural{te}[TE]{thermoelektrische}
\acro{tec}[TEC]{Thermoelektrischer Kühler}
\acro{teg}[TEG]{Thermoelektrischer Generator}
\acro{fteg}[FTEG]{flexibler TEG}
\acroplural{fteg}[FTEG]{flexible TEGs}
\acro{tteg}[TTEG]{Touristischer TEG}
\acro{tem}[TEM]{Thermoelement}
\acro{hex}[HEX]{Wärmetauscher}
\acro{zt}[ZT]{Gütezahl}

\end{acronym}

\chapter{Text}

\ac{cf} \ac{eh} \ac{ehs} \ac{ekg} \ac{fem} 

\ac{hh} \ac{ht} \ac{imd} \ac{iot} \ac{nt}

\ac{pcu} \ac{pf} \ac{pvc} \ac{sc} \ac{sps} 

\ac{te} \ac{tec} \ac{teg} \ac{fteg} \ac{tteg} 

\ac{tem} \ac{hex} \ac{zt}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- document class `article` has not defined `chapter`, you should use

  - `report` or `book` document class, or
  - instead `\chapter` use `\section`
- A possible solution is to insert `acronym` into `multicols` environment:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[printonlyused,nohyperlinks]{acronym}


\begin{document}
\chapter{Abkürzungen}

\begin{multicols}{2}
    \setlength\parskip{0pt}
    \begin{acronym}
\acro{cf}[CF]{Carbon Microfaser}
\acroplural{cf}[CF]{Carbon Microfasern}
\acro{eh}[EH]{Energy Harvesting}
\acro{ehs}[EHS]{Energy-Harvesting-System}
\acroplural{ehs}[EHS]{Energy-Harvesting-Systemen}
\acro{ekg}[EKG]{Elektrokardiogramm}
\acro{fem}[FEM]{Finite-Elemente-Methode}
\acro{hh}[HH]{Halb-Heusler-Verbindung}
\acroplural{hh}[HH]{Halb-Heusler-Verbindungen}
\acro{ht}[HT]{Hochtemperatur}
\acro{imd}[IMD]{implantiertes medizinisches Gerät}
\acroplural{imd}[IMD]{implantierten medizinischen Geräten}
\acro{iot}[IoT]{Internet of Things}
\acro{nt}[NT]{Niedertemperatur}
\acro{pcu}[PCU]{Power Control Unit}
\acro{pf}[PF]{Power Factor}
\acro{pvc}[PVC]{Polyvinylchlorid}
\acro{rfid}[RFID]{Radiofrequenz Identification}
\acro{sc}[SC]{Supply Chain}
\acro{sps}[SPS]{Funkenplasma-Sintern}
\acro{te}[TE]{thermoelektrisch}
\acroplural{te}[TE]{thermoelektrische}
\acro{tec}[TEC]{Thermoelektrischer Kühler}
\acroplural{tec}[TECs]{Thermoelektrische Kühler}
\acro{teg}[TEG]{Thermoelektrischer Generator}
\acroplural{teg}[TEGs]{Thermoelektrische Generatoren}
\acro{fteg}[FTEG]{flexibler TEG}
\acroplural{fteg}[FTEG]{flexible TEGs}
\acro{tteg}[TTEG]{Touristischer TEG}
\acro{tem}[TEM]{Thermoelement}
\acroplural{tem}[TEMs]{Thermoelemente}
\acro{hex}[HEX]{Wärmetauscher}
\acro{zt}[ZT]{Gütezahl}
    \end{acronym}
\end{multicols}


\chapter{Text}

\ac{cf} \ac{eh} \ac{ehs} \ac{ekg} \ac{fem}

\ac{hh} \ac{ht} \ac{imd} \ac{iot} \ac{nt}

\ac{pcu} \ac{pf} \ac{pvc} \ac{sc} \ac{sps}

\ac{te} \ac{tec} \ac{teg} \ac{fteg} \ac{tteg}

\ac{tem} \ac{hex} \ac{zt}

\end{document}
```

[image]